# How can I reformat the look/ format of an input dialog box in pine.script?

Tags: pine-script

I coded this looong study in pine and it gave me this dialog box with lots to scroll down to get to everything (see pic). I was wondering if there is a way to set up code so these individual input modules (1-4...) can be next to each other (Fig. II), rather than all below each other (Fig. I) ... creating this looooong scroll box? Every bit of help is much appreciated. Thx Y’all

[The input dialog box i’d like to reformat with code][1]

```
    study("ALL LINES", overlay=true)
    // GREEN STATS
    src = input(close, title="SRC Green")
    sm =input(1, title="Smooth Green")
    cd = input(1, title="CD Green")                                                 

    // RED STATS
    src2 = input(close, title="SRC RED")
    sm2 =input(1, title="Smooth Red")
    cd2 = input(1, title="CD Red")

    // WHITE STATS
    src3 = input(close, title="SRC White")
    sm3 =input(1, title="Smooth White")
    cd3 = input(1, title="CD White")

    // AQUA STATS
    src4 = input(close, title="SRC Aqua")
    sm4 =input(1, title="Smooth Aqua")
    cd4 = input(1, title="CD Aqua")

    // YELLOW STATS
    src5 = input(close, title="SRC Yellow")
    sm5 =input(1, title="Smooth Yellow")
    cd5 = input(1, title="CD Yellow")

    // MAIN CALC GREEN
    di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
    c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
    c2 = 1 - c1
    c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
    c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
    c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd
    i1 = c1*src + c2*nz(i1[1])
    i2 = c1*i1 + c2*nz(i2[1])
    i3 = c1*i2 + c2*nz(i3[1])
    i4 = c1*i3 + c2*nz(i4[1])
    i5 = c1*i4 + c2*nz(i5[1])
    i6 = c1*i5 + c2*nz(i6[1])
    bfr = -cd*cd*cd*i6 + c3*(i5) + c4*(i4) + c5*(i3)

    // MAIN CALC RED
    di2 = (sm2 - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
    c12 = 2 / (di2 + 1.0)
    c22 = 1 - c12
    c32 = 3.0 * (cd2 * cd2 + cd2 * cd2 * cd2)
    c42 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd2 * cd2 + cd2 + cd2 * cd2 * cd2)
    c52 = 3.0 * cd2 + 1.0 + cd2 * cd2 * cd2 + 3.0 * cd2 * cd2
    i12 = c12*src2 + c22*nz(i12[1])
    i22 = c12*i12 + c22*nz(i22[1])
    i32 = c12*i22 + c22*nz(i32[1])
    i42 = c12*i32 + c22*nz(i42[1])
    i52 = c12*i42 + c22*nz(i52[1])
    i62 = c12*i52 + c22*nz(i62[1])
    bfr2 = -cd2*cd2*cd2*i62 + c32*(i52) + c42*(i42) + c52*(i32)

    // MAIN CALC WHITE
    di3 = (sm3 - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
    c13 = 2 / (di3 + 1.0)
    c23 = 1 - c13
    c33 = 3.0 * (cd3 * cd3 + cd3 * cd3 * cd3)
    c43 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd3 * cd3 + cd3 + cd3 * cd3 * cd3)
    c53 = 3.0 * cd3 + 1.0 + cd3 * cd3 * cd3 + 3.0 * cd3 * cd3
    i13 = c13*src3 + c23*nz(i13[1])
    i23 = c13*i13 + c23*nz(i23[1])
    i33 = c13*i23 + c23*nz(i33[1])
    i43 = c13*i33 + c23*nz(i43[1])
    i53 = c13*i43 + c23*nz(i53[1])
    i63 = c13*i53 + c23*nz(i63[1])
    bfr3 = -cd3*cd3*cd3*i63 + c33*(i53) + c43*(i43) + c53*(i33)

    // MAIN CALC AQUA
    di4 = (sm4 - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
    c14 = 2 / (di4 + 1.0)
    c24 = 1 - c14
    c34 = 3.0 * (cd4 * cd4 + cd4 * cd4 * cd4)
    c44 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd4 * cd4 + cd4 + cd4 * cd4 * cd4)
    c54 = 3.0 * cd4 + 1.0 + cd4 * cd4 * cd4 + 3.0 * cd4 * cd4
    i14 = c14*src4 + c24*nz(i14[1])
    i24 = c14*i14 + c24*nz(i24[1]) 
    i34 = c14*i24 + c24*nz(i34[1])
    i44 = c14*i34 + c24*nz(i44[1])
    i54 = c14*i44 + c24*nz(i54[1])
    i64 = c14*i54 + c24*nz(i64[1])
    bfr4 = -cd4*cd4*cd4*i64 + c34*(i54) + c44*(i44) + c54*(i34)

    // MAIN CALC YELLOW
    di5 = (sm5 - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
    c15 = 2 / (di5 + 1.0)
    c25 = 1 - c15
    c35 = 3.0 * (cstrong textd5 * cd5 + cd5 * cd5 * cd5)
    c45 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd5 * cd5 + cd5 + cd5 * cd5 * cd5)
    c55 = 3.0 * cd5 + 1.0 + cd5 * cd5 * cd5 + 3.0 * cd5 * cd5
    i15 = c15*src5 + c25*nz(i15[1])
    i25 = c15*i15 + c25*nz(i25[1])
    i35 = c15*i25 + c25*nz(i35[1])
    i45 = c15*i35 + c25*nz(i45[1])
    i55 = c15*i45 + c25*nz(i55[1])
    i65 = c15*i55 + c25*nz(i65[1])
    bfr5 = -cd5*cd5*cd5*i65 + c35*(i55) + c45*(i45) + c55*(i35)
``    enter code here


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p1Jy.jpg
```

Comment: Your picture is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to group inputs in the way you show on your screenshot at the moment. That being said, Pine v4 has some functionality related to grouping inputs. If your indicator is not yet written in v4, you'd need to update it to v4. After that, adding a `group` argument to your inputs will group them together in a "block" of inputs with the group as their title. Adding the `inline` argument will display all the inputs with the same inline in one line. So you can have something like this:

```
//@version=4
study("ALL LINES", overlay=true)
// GREEN STATS
src = input(close, title="SRC",    group="Green", inline="Green")
sm  = input(1,     title="Smooth", group="Green", inline="Green")
cd  = input(1,     title="CD",     group="Green", inline="Green")                                                 
// RED STATS
src2 = input(close, title="SRC",    group="Red", inline="Red")
sm2  = input(1,     title="Smooth", group="Red", inline="Red")
cd2  = input(1,     title="CD",     group="Red", inline="Red")                                                 
// WHITE STATS
src3 = input(close, title="SRC",    group="White", inline="White")
sm3  = input(1,     title="Smooth", group="White", inline="White")
cd3  = input(1,     title="CD",     group="White", inline="White")                                                 
plot(close)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thats nice. Thx. Im in like my 5th week into all this coding and Pine. It sure is a rodeo.

Comment: At beeholder => since you have been a great help with ur last answer to my 1st question on here...Would it  be ok to ask u to look at my 2nd question here on stack’s about my issue I am having with Pine’s “ line.new “? So far this has kept me up a couple nights already. Seems its unsolvable .. TradingView support only can refer me back on here...they don’t have a clue about the issue ;-(.